# Feeding into preparedstatements effectively

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I am using PreparedStatement in my code since I have a lot of special characters to insert into the database.

Some of my tables have a lot of columns, so it seems a bit of an overkill to have to assign one parameter at a time. Is there a better/more effiecient of specifying the parameters?

Cheers!

Comment: Overkill is clearly the wrong expression here. Since the taste of people differs: What do you describe as `lot of columns`? 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000?

Comment: In terms of efficiency, this is it. In terms of convenience, you'll need to write your own utility code. JDBC is primarily about raw performance, not convenience.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear to me what your problem is.

The parameters have to be set in the PreparedStatement individually - this is because you need to tell the PreparedStatement how to represent your different Java objects in the database.

However, you could easily write a class/method that would allow you to pass in an Object[] of args, and which could then be added to PreparedStatement with the appropriate index and object handling.

Something along the lines of:

```
private static void setParameters(PreparedStatement stmt, Object[] args){
  for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
    setArgument(stmt, i+1, args[i]);
  }
}

private static void setArgument(PreparedStatement stmt, int index, Object arg){
  if (arg instanceof MyObject){
    stmt.set[X](index, handleMyObject(arg));
  }
}
```